# How to set classpath in spring tool suite

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have added a grails project to workspace and i want to set the classpath.how to do this.
I am not able to find an option to set the classpath in project->properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a grails project, you should be setting your classpath through grails, rather than through STS.  I assume that you already have the Grails Tooling of STS installed.

The way that you alter a grails project's classpath depends on what you are trying to do.  Please explain exactly what you are trying to do and I can perhaps be more specific.

Comment: @Vinay, please consider either accepting Andrew's answer, adding your own answer, or deleting the question.  Was your solution worth sharing?